# Monitoring tools for non-distro Hadoop

Tags: monitoring, hadoop

I've built a Hadoop cluster by installing most packages manually (using binaries or source). I opted not to use a custom distribution like Cloudera, MapR or Hortonworks, since I wanted the flexibility that comes with choosing what packages and versions to use.

However, most of these distros have excellent admin and monitoring tools, which would make our dev-ops' life simpler. Are there any such tools out there that are distro-free? I don't care if they are free or licensed, just that they'd work with a custom built cluster. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few. Check exchange.nagios.org and you will find plenty plugins to monitor hdfs, tasktrachers, namenodes and more.

See this ppt for graphing resource usage using cacti and nagios checks -- http://files.meetup.com/1228907/How%20to%20monitor%20the.ppt